# How to check if a type is a primtive array in Java?

Tags: java, primitive-types

I am trying to filter methods which has primitive arrays as their arguments.
One of the method signature is as follows:

```
public void myMeth(int[]);
public void myMeth(double[]);
```

Executing the following program,

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

      System.out.println(int[].class);
      System.out.println(int[].class.isPrimitive());

      System.out.println(Integer[].class);

      System.out.println(int.class);
      System.out.println(int.class.isPrimitive());
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
class [I
false
class [Ljava.lang.Integer;
int
true
```

Now my questions are:

1. Since `int` is primitive type, why is not `int[]` primitive?
2. How to know if a type is a primitive array?

Comment: Why are you all downvoting? This is a properly phrased question! It states a problem, it asks a reasonable question (the second one), it shows some attempt, ... What else do you want?

Comment: strongly related [In Java, how do I dynamically determine the type of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/212805/85421)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Since `int` is primitive type, why is not `int[]` primitive?

Any array is an object in Java because it can be created with `new` operator as follows:

```
int[] a = new int[5];
```

Also, array is a sub-class of Object, therefore you can call all Object class' methods on the array object.

```
  int[] a = new int[5];
  int x = 10;
  System.out.println(a.toString());
  System.out.println(x.toString()); // compile-time error
```

From the [Java Specification: Section #4.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1)

> *An object is a class instance or **an array**.*

So, the condition `(type.isArray() && type.isPrimitive())` is always `false` because array is not a primitive type.

---

> 2. How to know if a type is a primitive array?

You need to make use of the `getComponentType()` method. From [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getComponentType--)

> Returns the Class representing the component type of an array. If this
>   class does not represent an array class this method returns null.

So, the code snippet would be:

```
public static boolean isPrimitiveArray(Class<?> type) {
        Class<?> componentType = type;
        while ((componentType = componentType.getComponentType()) != null) {
            if (componentType.isPrimitive()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

  System.out.println(isPrimitiveArray(int[].class)); // true
  System.out.println(isPrimitiveArray(int[][].class)); // true
  System.out.println(isPrimitiveArray(int[][][].class)); // true

  System.out.println(isPrimitiveArray(Integer.class)); // false
  System.out.println(isPrimitiveArray(Integer[].class)); // false
  System.out.println(isPrimitiveArray(int.class)); // false
```

or if we want to check dimensions also..

```
public static boolean isPrimitiveArray(Class<?> type, int dimensions) {
        Class<?> componentType = type;
        int count = 0;
        while ((componentType = componentType.getComponentType()) != null) {
            count++;
            if (componentType.isPrimitive() && dimensions == count) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }


  System.out.println(isPrimitiveArray(int[].class,1)); // true
  System.out.println(isPrimitiveArray(int[][].class,2)); // true
  System.out.println(isPrimitiveArray(int[][][].class,2)); // false
```

Comment: Is this some kind of blog post that you decided to share on SO for some reason or...

Comment: @it'sBritneybitch No, I wanted to ask this, but I got the answer while writing the question, so I made use of the Q&A style! ;)

Comment: You do realise you could have closed/deleted your question if you found an answer?

Comment: @it'sBritneybitch self-answers are allowed and encouraged on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: "array is an object in Java because it can be created with new operator" isn't it the other way around: "it must be created by `new` because it is an object?" [:- )

Comment: @it'sBritneybitch But since there is no proper reason to close the question (neither off-topic/duplicate/opinion-based/need details/need focus) and also what then is the use of Q&A style? I still don't understand why the question is downvoted!

Comment: @luk2302 I didn't realise this, to me it looks like some kind of blog post shared on a wrong place.

Comment: @it'sBritneybitch Self-answers appear like blog posts, they may *reference* other SO answers or blog posts, but it is nevertheless *alright* so far as SO is concerned.

Comment: @it'sBritneybitch And that is okay as long as it is written to fit the Q&A pattern, which it does imho. OP simply had a problem, there was no SO answer for it in place so OP had to come up with his own solution. And instead of keeping the knowledge to himself OP posted it for us all to gain some insight and for future readers, that is what SO is.