# How to remove duplicates from an array generically?

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

This is the code I have right now

```
public class removerDuplicados<T> {

    public removerDuplicados() {
    }

    public T[] removerDups(T [] arr) {
        T[] res = Arrays.stream(arr).distinct().toArray();
        return res;
    }
}
```

But this line

```
T[] res = Arrays.stream(arr).distinct().toArray();
```

Gives me incompatible types error

Comment: try using `T[] res = (T[]) (Arrays.stream(arr).distinct().toArray()) ;`

Comment: @MattDog_222Overwatch Doesn't work. Arrays aren't generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
The copy is redundant, but it can be compiled without reflections, casting or warnings.

```
public static <T> T[] removerDups(T [] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr)
        .distinct()
        .toArray(n -> Arrays.copyOf(arr, n));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] array = {"a", "b", "a"};
    String[] uniq = removerDups(array);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(uniq));
}
```

output:

```
[a, b]
```

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly enough, you can't do this particular trick with collections, where types are erased, but you can with arrays:

```
// this method can be static
@SuppressWarnings("unsafe") // safe because we're getting the type from the array object
public static <T> T[] removeDups(T[] arr) {
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212805/in-java-how-do-i-dynamically-determine-the-type-of-an-array
  Class<T> componentType = (Class<T>) arr.getClass().getComponentType();

  return Arrays.stream(arr)
    .distinct()
    .toArray(size -> (T[]) Array.newInstance(componentType, size));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work. Just call removerDuplicados.removerDups( ARRAY_NAME )

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class removerDuplicados<T>
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T[] removerDups(T [] arr)
    {
        return ( (T[]) (Arrays.stream(arr).distinct().toArray()) ) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work because `Object[]` is not a `T[]`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Don't downvote my comment before trying it. It literally compiles. Copy paste it and run this in a main class        `public static void main(String[] args)
       {
              Integer[] ints = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 1 } ;
              System.out.println(Arrays.toString(removerDuplicados.removerDups(ints) ));
          }`

Comment: Now try `ints = removeDups(ints);`. You'll get a `ClassCastException`. Your example works because `T` is `Object`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Yeah but even your answer wont work because it doesn't have a return type and you would have to individually cast each thing to type T I think

Comment: Missing return type fixed. You don't need to cast each stream member; that's handled as part of the type-safe version of `toArray`.